# Are there other words in American English that use the same vowel sound as the "as" in "Pasta"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, loanwords

Obviously, pasta is a loanword, but generally loanwords are pronounced with the closest vowels which already exist in the language.

In American English, the "a" in pasta is the same vowel that I hear in RP British English words like "grass", "fast" and "arm".  Which is strange, because that *isn't* how Americans pronounce words with a long a sound in RP such as "fast", "last" and "bath".

In British English, "pasta" has a short A. In my dialect, there is **no** trap-bath split, so I pronounce "pasta" the same as I would words such as "past" and "cast".

I asked in the original question if pasta had the same vowel as "lost" and "mop".  The answer seems to have been no, but that it *is* the same vowel as *father*.

This is a little confusing, and I understand that most American accents have a "father-bother" merger, so it's confusing to me that pasta *does* share a vowel with father, but not with *lost*

In order to narrow it down, in terms of their vowels,  how does the following list fit together in the majority of American Accents (I've grouped them based on my accent)

> calm
>      father
>
> bother
>      mop
>      lost
>      on
>
> fast
>      pasta

*(I've left out "caught" words, as I don't think it's relevant here, but if I'm wrong and should have chosen some different words, then please do correct me).*

Comment: Does "father" sound different to you?

Comment: Google *cot-caught merger* and see if that helps you.

Comment: Where specifically are you hearing this? I'm in the Midwest, and don't hear anything unusual in the pasta vowel (I'm unmerged, and use/hear the *caught* vowel, same as in the name *Costa* or word *roster*), but that doesn't mean there aren't dialects that do it differently.

Comment: Well, first you have to decide how to pronounce "pasta".

Comment: @1006a Honestly, I've always noticed it when watching how they pronounce *pasta* in friends.  Maybe it's the Italian influence, but it's the same here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/pasta .  The American one is the same vowel in RP English "Past" to my ears.

Comment: *pasta* has the *father* vowel. Both *lost* and *grass* are totally different.

Comment: @tchrist They're very close in *pasta* and BrE *grass*, though, more so than between *pasta* and (some?) AmE *grass*. I'm curious - in AmE, for those that pronounce *grass* with the vowel sound of *air* (I'm approximating), do they pronounce *pasta* with a similar vowel sound (to *air*)?

Comment: Spanish and Italian only have the FATHER vowel for their "a", so *taco* and *pasta* have that vowel. So too do *basta, capo, canto, casa, cha-cha, chakra, drama, fado, gaga, haha, java, llama, lava, macho, mambo, mama, masa, Paco, raza.*  I have never heard any American use the /æ/ vowel in those words, only the /ɑ/ vowel. Americans tease Brits about having the "wrong" vowel in their *macho taco pasta*. :)

Comment: @Lawrence I can't answer that because I've never heard Americans pronouncing  /æ/  in those words, only ever /ɑ/. Regarding *air*, many of us have not   TRAP's /æ/ in that word but rather the same /e/ monophthong that we also have in *merry, marry, Mary, make, made, aim, gain, game, grape, gate*.

Comment: @tchrist could be wrong here, but I think "make - merry" is a minority one still.  I say that, because it always jumps out at me when I hear words like "play" and "make" in those accents, in the same way I always notice those American accents that pronounce "egg" like "vague" and "plague"; if everyone was doing it, it wouldn't jump out so much.   Also, I think Lawrence says "air", I think he is referring to the fact to the standard vowel in American "grass"; it sounds a lot like the British "less" and "air" so I think that's what he was trying to describe.

Comment: @Lawrence no. That's what brought my question about. Americans who pronounce the words "past" and "fast" with that "eh" sound, pronounce "pasta" with the "ah" sound, which always sounded odd to me. see here: dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/past dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/pasta dictionary.cambridge.org/pronunciation/english/fast

Comment: @tchrist please see updated question, these comments have cleared up a lot for me with some of my assumptions about American vowels, and I think the question is more pointed now

Comment: Ranging between somewhat related and so closely related as to be near- or exact duplicates, please see the following questions which I here order strictly by seniority (eldest first) not by how closely related they are: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/2337,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/7998,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/10155,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/31022,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/70927,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/77510,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/96434,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/138705, [*to be continued*]

Comment: [*continued*] http://english.stackexchange.com/q/143052,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/146641,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/276763,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/303766,
http://english.stackexchange.com/a/333145,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/334210,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/334557,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/342107,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/352705,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/367098,
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/373277. Pay especial note to "linguisticky" answers by John Lawler, RegDwight, nohat, sumelic, Peter Shor, etc.

Comment: @tchrist has it "right" by California standards ..as he put it "pasta has the father vowel. Both lost and grass are totally different"

Comment: In this day and age of online dictionaries that will play a recording at the touch of a button, why are you having so much trouble with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most American speakers use more-or-less the vowel of RP (Received Pronunciation, the most common or standard "reference" British English accent) "grass", "fast" and "arm" in all of *pasta, father, mop, don.* But not *lost*; that has a different vowel in "GA" ("General American," the "standard" reference American accent). "Lost" and "mop" have different vowels in "General American" English due to a vowel change similar to the one that is responsible for the different vowels of "last" and "lap" in RP British English. "Pasta" and "father" have the same vowel as "mop," but not the same vowel as "lost" in GA.

The vowel in the word "father" is typically written /ɑː/ when transcribing British English, with a vowl length marker (ː) because British English is often analyzed as having phonological vowel length.

Vowel length is less important (or at least, less obvious) in the phonological system of American English, so usually it is just written /ɑ/ when transcribing American speech.

Of course, as with all IPA vowel symbols, this is a simplified representation of a variable set of actual vowel sounds.

#### Distribution of /ɑ/ in a typical American English accent

You can see some explanation in the Wikipedia article [*Pronunciation of English ⟨a⟩*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_of_English_%E2%9F%A8a%E2%9F%A9#Development_of_the_new_long_A). Basically, /ɑ/ is usual in rhotic American English accents for *father,* before /r/ (also analyzed as a unitary rhotic vowel /ɑ˞/), and for the majority of speakers, in some words that historically had a "short o" such as *lot.* The exception is words like *cloth* and *lost* where "short o" ended up being changed to  the "aw" vowel of *thought*.

Words like *palm* also historically had /ɑ/, but the common restoration of /l/ has caused some speakers to change the vowel to the *thought* vowel (/ɔ/).

Comment: *Lost* has the THOUGHT vowel.

Comment: @tchrist: whoops, I even mentioned the *cloth* set but I forgot "lost" is in it. Thanks; fixing.

Comment: So I hadn't thought of the "palm" (without the l) vowel.  Reading more about the trap bath split, I see that elongated "a" sounds then merged with the **existing** "long a" of father and palm, whereas I'd been thinking that vowel was a new creation starting at that split (based on an observation that older speakers of northern accents tend to have a short a in father as well as bath and grass)

Comment: Most but not all words of the form ***CaCa*** and ***CaCo*** in English have the /ɑ/ FATHER vowel for that first "a": for example *basta, canto, capo, casa, cha-cha, chakra, drama, Fado, flaco, gaga, grappa, ha-ha, Java, lava, llama, macho, mama, mambo, masa, natto, Paco, pasta, raza, taco*.  Some words of longer assimilation have been spelled with a doubled consonant to indicate that they should be said with the  /æ/ TRAP vowel: *lasso, lassie, calla lily, canna lily*. But *hosta lilies* sounds like *pasta lilies* save for the h/p distinction. :)

Comment: @tchrist out of those words that I have ever said/heard, more than half of them have a short "a" sound in my accent (and I think BrE in general).  Lasso and lassie are both to prevent /z/ I think rather than /ɑ/.  Canna and calla are both from Latin, and preserve the original spelling.  Canto, capo, casa, chakra, grappa, mama, mambo, paco, pasta, natto, taco would be short for me (and I think all other Brits).  Long a would be only be cha-cha, drama, gaga, java, lava, llama and raza.  Basta, Fado, flaco and masa, I've never heard out loud.

Comment: @Some_Guy There is also *plaza* and *playa*, both with the a of *father* rather than the one of *lazy*. But *patio* and *canyon* have the third a from *cat*. I would avoid calling any of those short and long though: American children are taught to call the /e/ of *lazy* "long a".

Comment: In my Midwestern twang (pre NCS) father, pasta, arm (and palm and casa) go together; grass, fast, past (and capo) have the same sound.

Comment: do people really say "arm" and "grass" the same way ?  Hmm.. shows you how we don't necessarily hear things as people say them ; )

Comment: @Tom22 no, I think you've misread the comment

Comment: @Some_Guy .. well I quoted him verbatim .. I did mean to include a wink though after the "right" part ; ) ... I'm not sure there is a "right" way to pronounce vowels.. only "common" ways

Comment: @Tom22: Yep; in many British accents "grass" rhymes with "arse" and "arm" rhymes with "Guam."

Comment: @tom22 turns out it was me who misread your comment, sorry

Comment: I apologize for the downvote.  I forgot what RP means.  I will edit the answer so that I can change my vote.

Comment: Do you want to take out my "sort of standard"?  I didn't know about the southern thing.

Comment: @aparente001: I think it's accurate; I just changed it to avoid any possible arguments about the "standard"ness of accents from e.g. Northern England or Scotland.

Comment: What do they do with *pasta* in the north?  (Can I say "in the north" to encompass both?)  I consulted a dictionary that claimed to have a British recording of pasta, and they only gave one version.

Comment: @aparente001: I believe in northern British accents, "pasta" would have the vowel of "trap", as in RP, but unlike in RP, "fast" and "bath" would also have the vowel of "trap" for many northern speakers.